# unable receive the response with Okhttp sometimes

Tags: android, kotlin

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://example.com:PORT/... http/1.1
    Authorization: Bearer example token
    Device-Type: Android
    --> END GET
```

I just see request information and I will not get any error/response.

I using Retrofit and Okhttp.

The configuration is as follows:

```
private val timeOut: Long = 30 * 1000
private val cacheSize: Long = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB
private var cache = Cache(presenterLayer.getCacheDir(), cacheSize)


private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(RedirectInterceptor())
        .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor(presenterLayer))
        .addInterceptor(Logger(presenterLayer))
        .cache(cache)
        .sslSocketFactory(CustomTrust.getSSLConfig().socketFactory)
        .followRedirects(false)
        .followSslRedirects(false)
        .connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()


private val retrofit = Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .baseUrl(presenterLayer.getBaseUrl())
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

My question is: what times does this happen except the network and what exactly happened?

Comment: if you use emulator please be careful . i had same problem and when removed my emulator and created another one every thing was fine!

Comment: you can use breakpoint in onResponse and onFailure , then run in debug mode to check every things

Comment: Dear iman thanks, I do not use an emulator.. This problem is seen on the device of a thousand users

Comment: your address is "https://example.com:PORT" , are you ok this server exist ?

Comment: Dear @AdnanAbdollahZaki  the address is for example

Comment: @MohammadRezaEram , check your Proxy , maybe your server doesn't response with proxy . disable or enable and double check it .

Comment: Your timeout is too high... 500 minutes before you get a Timeout error in case of network issues

Answer (score 2):

try `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` for **timeOut** and check error request

```
private val timeOut: Long = 30 * 1000

.connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```